# How to reduce vram usage?

Tags: modeling, rendering, gpu, memory-management

[image]
[image]

I'm making interior scene like these picture and also more different scene.

I'm Using only 2k textures, except HDRI image, and rendering with tiling (512) and also other setting included.  But it already take 7.4/ 8(total), so I cannot add more object for detail.

How can I solve it? Not buying new one.

Comment: All the identical object we see here, are they duplicates or instances?

Comment: Hi, It is istance. alt+d and collection instances. I didn't use shift +d